# How to write testable code and be able to test it?

Tags: php, phpunit, silex

I'm writing `ConfigServiceProvider` for the Silex application that will be load application config (like "debug" vallue) and other services' config. In such provider I need to read actual **yaml** files from filesystem, parse it, and load to `$app`. This is the main purpose of this provider. But how can I test this piece of code? Should I test it, or I can mock function?

```
private function /*ConfigServiceProvider::*/parseYamlFile($filename)
{
    return $app["yaml.parser"]->parse(file_get_content(
        $app["config.locator"]->locate($filename)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that can be tested in this method is that the right calls are being made.

You test that by mocking the parser and the config locator, and you also need to get rid of the `file_get_content` call, use a library, and mock that too.

If you want to check if the yaml parser works as expected, then you should write a test for that library.